# How to store array in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, json

I have to store an array in `window.localStorage`. How would I store the array in `window.localStorage` using console window?

```
EX:
cards: Array[0]
length: 0
```

I have to store this. Now here key is cards and length is nested.

Comment: JSON.stringify()  and JSON.parse() upon reading?

Answer (score 5):

`localStorage` only support `string` so you'll have to parse it to `JSON`

```js
var arr = ["hello", "how", "are", "you", "doing"];

localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnjjrs7z/)